# How to write a function that runs certain SQL on certain columns in a PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[image]

I wrote some code and have this as output. The left side is basically the columns of a dataframe that I'm working with, and the right side is the SQL query that needs to be run on that particular column.

Now I want to write a function that runs the queries on the right on the columns on the left and display the output.

The first picture is basically the values of the 'Column' and 'Query' columns of another dataframe. I used .collect() methods to retrieve those values.

[image]

This seemed like a simple problem but I'm still stuck at it. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a subset of your data

```
data_ls = [
    ('maxpulse', 'select count(*) from {table} where {col} is null'),
    ('duration', 'select round((count(distinct {col}) / count({col})) * 100) from {table}')
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['column', 'query'])

# +--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |column  |query                                                                  |
# +--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |maxpulse|select count(*) from {table} where {col} is null                       |
# |duration|select round((count(distinct {col}) / count({col})) * 100) from {table}|
# +--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Approach 1: Using UDF**

```
def createQuery(query_string, column_name=None, table_name=None):
    if column_name is not None and table_name is None:
        fnlquery = query_string.format(col=column_name, table='{table}')
    elif column_name is None and table_name is not None:
        fnlquery = query_string.format(col='{col}', table=table_name)
    elif column_name is not None and table_name is not None:
        fnlquery = query_string.format(col=column_name, table=table_name)
    else:
        fnlquery = query_string

    return fnlquery

createQueryUDF = func.udf(createQuery, StringType())

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('final_query', createQueryUDF('query', 'column')). \
    select('final_query'). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |final_query                                                                  |
# +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |select count(*) from {table} where maxpulse is null                          |
# |select round((count(distinct duration) / count(duration)) * 100) from {table}|
# +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Approach 2: Using [`regexp_replace()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) sql function**

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('final_query', func.expr('regexp_replace(query, "[\{]col[\}]", column)')). \
    select('final_query'). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |final_query                                                                  |
# +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |select count(*) from {table} where maxpulse is null                          |
# |select round((count(distinct duration) / count(duration)) * 100) from {table}|
# +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

*Similar approach can be used to replace `'{table}'` with a table name.* The final queries from the `final_query` field can then be collected (using `.collect()`) and used further to run sql queries.

```
query_list = data_sdf. \
    withColumn('final_query', func.expr('regexp_replace(query, "[\{]col[\}]", column)')). \
    select('final_query'). \
    rdd.map(lambda x: x.final_query). \
    collect()
# ['select count(*) from {table} where maxpulse is null',
#  'select round((count(distinct duration) / count(duration)) * 100) from {table}']

# run the queries by iterating over the list
for query in query_list:
    spark.sql(query)
```

Comment: thank you, this was helpful. But on what dataframe should I use the .collect() method to retrieve the queries? When I'm using this method on my dataframe it's giving me the values of the original dataframe only

Comment: e.g., in my last approach, just replace `show()` with `collect()` to get the queries as a list.

Comment: Can you show by incorporating in the code?

Comment: do you mean you require the query strings in a list where you can iterate and run the queries?

Comment: yes exactly that

Answer (score 1):

You can put column names and queries to a dictionary:

```
dct = {'column_name': 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE {col} IS NULL'}

for k, v in dct.items():
    q = v.format(col = k)
    # spark.sql(q)
    print(q)
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name IS NULL
```

Comment: This approach makes sense. But I'm getting a key error as I need to register my dataframe as a table first in order to perform sql queries. Can that be integrated in the function?

Comment: @AishaniSingh I don't understand why I want to keep those queries in a dataframe?

Comment: It's for a data certification project, just to have clarity on what rule i.e. query has to be run on what column